# How to do query to Hive/Spark Thrift Server using http request

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Typically, we are using JDBC API to connect to Hive/Spark Thrift server and do query with jdbc connection url like `jdbc:hive2://server:port`

I would ask if the Hive/Spark Thrift Server is using Http transport mode, How could I send query via http request?

Some code example would be very helpful,Thanks

I ask so because I am not using Java client to access Hive/Spark server.

Comment: In addition to the JDBC drivers _(the lame one from Apache code base & the decent one from Cloudera based on a commercial SDK & the costly one from DataDirect)_ you can find ODBC drivers _(from Horton, Cloudera, DataDirect)_ and Python clients _(incl. `impyla` sponsored by Cloudera)_. That should be enough for all tastes...

Comment: You could also use Apache Livy to expose the entire Spark context as an HTTP interface